# Did Arex or any member of his species appear in other Star Trek media?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tas

A weird character from *Star Trek: The Animated Series* is Arex. For those that don't remember him, here's a picture:

[image]

I was wondering if him or a member of his species appeared in either a film, TV series, book, or other form of media. This includes in the form of a mention or a physical appearance.

Comment: yes - most notably and recently - the Titan novels - http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Edosian

Answer (score 3):

According to Memory Alpha, Arex is featured in the [*Star Trek* series of comic books published by DC](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_(DC_volume_1)), beginning in issue #37, "[Choices!](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Choices!)".

[image: Two panels of Arex speaking with Scotty]

He is also listed as appearing in the following novels:

- [The Galactic Whirlpool](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Galactic_Whirlpool)
- [Time for Yesterday](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Time_for_Yesterday)
- [The Fire and the Rose](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Fire_and_the_Rose)

Another member of his species, Kershu, is featured in various *Star Trek: Titan* novels.

Comment: re: your comment on memory-alpha: that is not true - see the link in the comment I made a few minutes ago. The Titan novels have a secondary character that is Edosian. If you mean to say there are no other official canon references, that is correct, but, technically speaking, memory-alpha *does* mention another character :)  (you still have my upvote)

Comment: @NKCampbell Ah, I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: ... and a whole bunch of other stuff you've not mentioned; http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Arex_Na_Eth